# What is good way to fix web browser rendering problem on pixels (responsive)

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

Browser has rendering problem just 1 pixel but mostly it's important for design. It's happening very often when I'm using **CSS pseudo-element** and positioning them by `absolute` on `relative`. I tested on [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/). I think other browsers have the same problem too.

I have a [*pen*](https://codepen.io/Guja1501/pen/KboyPx) on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) which has exactly same problem I said above. (If you don't see any problem try responsive)

So what is good way to fix web browser rendering problem on pixels (responsive)?

Check this screenshot:
[image]

White lines on image is not desired. Each element is rectangle with before and after pseudo-element which represents triangles. In the end all elements must be hexagon. So each element has 1px transparent line between horizontal siblings and between pseudo-elements too. That's the problem

Comment: What's the desired behavior and what happens instead? It's not very clear from the screenshot you shared.

Comment: White lines on image is not desired. Each element is rectangle with `before` and `after` pseudo-element which represents triangles. So each element has **1px transparent** line between horizontal siblings and between pseudo-elements too.